# How can I disable implicit lamba variable capture?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

How can I disable implicit lambda variable capture?

For example if I have a lambda that's doing being called on each entry in an array and I don't want to capture any variables, how can I disable the implicit capture?  I prefer using explicit capture lists because it means I'm only grabbing what I think I'm grabbing.

---

Turns out I was profoundly mistaken about how `[]` captures worked.  Just in case anyone finds this in the future, here's some hopefully help information in addition to the accepted answer to my (misguided) question above.

> Capture list can be passed as follows:
>
> - `[a,&b]` where a is captured by copy and b is captured by reference.
> - `[this]` captures the current object (*this) by reference
> - `[&]` captures all automatic variables used in the body of the lambda by reference and current object by reference if exists
> - `[=]` captures all automatic variables used in the body of the lambda by copy and current object by reference if exists
> - `[]` captures nothing
>
> A variable can be used without being captured if it does not have automatic storage duration (i.e. it is not a local variable or it is static or thread local) or if it is not odr-used in the body of the lambda.
>
> Source: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda

In other words, if you want to disable implicit capture, just use and empty set of brackets `[]`.

Comment: What "implicit capture"?? Afaik there is no such thing.

Comment: You need to provide some code explaining what you mean: default behavior from lambdas is to not capture any local variables, and it's impossible to not capture global variables.

Comment: @JesperJuhl There is such a thing as "implicit capture" when it comes to type definitions, but it's not clear that that's what the OP is talking about...

Comment: Have you tried simply not using the variable inside your lambda?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only "implicit capture" happens with the static and global variables in the scope. And there's no way to get rid of this.

Comment: Nor does there need to be since those captures come for free: the compiler knows at compile time the address of such variables so it's trivial to access them.